# JSON String inside a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, escaping, stringify

I want to create a JSON string inside a JSON request. Here is my code,

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjpnbqz4/)

**JS**

```
var x = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'a sample text',
};

var request = {
    t: JSON.stringify(x),
    c: 2,
    r: 'some text'
};

console.log(request);
```

Can someone help me how to escape the double quotes?

**Console**

```
Object {
  t: "{"a":1,"b":"a sample text"}", //This creates a problem, double quotes inside double quotes.
  c: 2, 
  r: "some text"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have a problem. If you do `JSON.stringify(request)` you'll get a perfectly valid JSON object. You can then `JSON.parse` that and confirm you get back an identical object to the original.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there isn't actually a problem here.

Comment: Properly escaping quotation marks is only an issue when using string **literals**. You have to escape them so that the *parser* understands where the string value ends. However, you are generating the string *programmatically*, the parser is not involved anymore at this point.

Comment: My bad. Its a silly question to ask someone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just the way the browser console shows you the value of a string, by wrapping in double quotes for the output. This is perfectly normal and nothing is broken.

You can test it by transforming your JSON string back to an object and using a property.

```
console.log( JSON.parse(request.t).b ); // a sample text
```

Comment: console.log( JSON.parse(request.t) ); should be enough if you are building a json inside another json.

Answer (score 18):

There is no problem. It's just your `console.log` that shows all strings by simply delimiting with `"`.

As you say this `request` object is used in a JSON request, where it will be `JSON.stringify`ed another time, with the valid result

```
{"t":"{\"a\":1,\"b\":\"a sample text\"}","c":2,"r":"some text"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this may not be helpful. But, I ran into an issue where the JSON string inside a JSON had no property. I was able to parse the JSON string doing the following:

```
//Return from remote php request {'{"firsttest": 0, ""scndTest": 1"}'};
// How to access 
let data = Object.Keys(jsonWJsonString)[0];
let justJSONValue = JSON.parse(data);
```

this works because there is no object property to reference so an index value can be used; which gives us the JSONString. Hope that helped anyone. Cheers